# Pygame Sprite movement, failing to update

Tags: python-3.x, pygame, sprite

I shall try to reframe my problem as a more succinct and specific question. Below is the Hero class with a couple more print commands to the terminal that I'm trying to use to sort out what's going wrong:

Code:

```
class Hero(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    """Moves the hero around the screen, following the mouse"""
    #male = load_image("malehero-64.png", -1)
    #female = load_image("girlhero-64.png", -1)
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image, self.rect = load_image("girlhero-64.png", -1)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.topleft = (384,0)
        self.target = self.movetarget()

    #def setgender(self, gender):
        #if gender == "male":
            #self.image, self.rect = self.male
        #if gender == "female":
            #self.image, self.rect = self.female
        #self.startingpos = (480, 640)
        #self.rect.topleft = (480,640)
        #self.target = self.rect.topleft

    def movetarget(self):
        self.pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.target = self.rect.topleft
        self.targetx,self.targety = self.target
        self.oldx, self.oldy = self.rect.topleft
        if self.oldx + tilesize < self.pos[0]:
            self.targetx = self.oldx + tilesize
        if self.oldx > self.pos[0]:
            self.targetx = self.oldx - tilesize
        if self.oldx + tilesize >= self.pos[0] and self.oldx < self.pos[0]:
            self.targetx = self.oldx
        if self.oldy + tilesize < self.pos[1]:
            self.targety = self.oldy + tilesize
        if self.oldy > self.pos[1]:
            self.targety = self.oldy - tilesize
        if self.oldy + tilesize >= self.pos[1] and self.oldy < self.pos[1]:
            self.targety = self.oldy
        self.target = (self.targetx,self.targety)
        print("NOW THE TARGET IS SET!!!!!!!!")
        print(self.targetx,self.targety)
        return self.target

    def update(self):
        "Move the hero closer to the last mouse position clicked self.target"
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        print("topleft before")
        print(self.rect.topleft)
        self.xmove = 0
        self.ymove = 0
        print("update target is")
        print(self.target)
        if self.rect.topleft[0] > 960:
            self.rect.topleft = (960, self.rect.topleft[1])
        if self.rect.topleft[0] < 0:
            self.rect.topleft = (0, self.rect.topleft[1])
        if self.rect.topleft[0] >= 0 and self.rect.topleft[0] <= 960:
            if self.rect.topleft[0] < self.target[0]:
                self.xmove = 4
            if self.rect.topleft[1] < self.target[1]:
                self.ymove = 4
            if self.rect.topleft[0] > self.target[0]:
                self.xmove = -4
            if self.rect.topleft[1] > self.target[1]:
                self.ymove = -4
        self.newx=self.rect.topleft[0]+self.xmove
        self.newy=self.rect.topleft[1]+self.ymove
        print("newx and newy")
        print (self.newx,self.newy)
        self.rect.topleft = (self.newx,self.newy)
        print("topleft after")
        print(self.rect.topleft)
```

When run, a snippet of the terminal is as follows:

Code:

```
NOW THE TARGET IS SET!!!!!!!!
64 64
NOW THE TARGET IS SET!!!!!!!!
64 64
NOW THE TARGET IS SET!!!!!!!!
64 64
NOW THE TARGET IS SET!!!!!!!!
64 64
topleft before
(0, 0)
update target is
(0, 0)
newx and newy
0 0
topleft after
(0, 0)
topleft before
(0, 0)
update target is
(0, 0)
newx and newy
0 0
topleft after
(0, 0)
topleft before
(0, 0)
update target is
(0, 0)
newx and newy
0 0
topleft after
(0, 0)
```

What I am attempting to accomplish:
When the mouse is clicked on the game map, Hero.movetarget is called, and sets a movement target one tile distant from the current rect. Then, when the charactersprites group calls the update methods(is that the correct term here?) on all sprites in the group, they should move a few pixels towards that target tile.

I had the sprites doing this without issue when the update method was simply moving all sprites one tile in a leap. I'm trying to change it so that the sprites glide over several frames to their new target tile, rather than simply leaping there.

As I read the terminal printout above, the self.target variable set in Hero.movetarget is not the same as the self.target printed to terminal at the beginning of Hero.update.

I don't understand why changing self.target in Hero.movetarget isn't changing self.target in Hero.update.

Please excuse any ignorance in my phrasing of the question, and thank you in advance for any insight you can provide.

The load_image class is taken from the Pygame chimp tutorial:
Code:

```
def load_image(name, colorkey=None):
    fullname = os.path.join('data', name)
    try:
        image = pygame.image.load(fullname)
    except pygame.error as message:
        print ('Cannot load image:', name)
        raise SystemExit(message)
    image = image.convert()
    if colorkey is not None:
        if colorkey is -1:
            colorkey = image.get_at((0,0))
        image.set_colorkey(colorkey, RLEACCEL)
    return image, image.get_rect()
```

The body of the program that calls the Hero class, edited to what I think are the relevant portions:
Code:

```
hero = Hero()

charactersprites = pygame.sprite.Group((hero))

mathsterGroup = pygame.sprite.Group()
mathster = Mathster((0, 0))
mathsterGroup.add((mathster))
charactersprites.add((mathster))
mathster = Mathster((128, 256))
mathsterGroup.add((mathster))
charactersprites.add((mathster))
mathster = Mathster((512, 320))
mathsterGroup.add((mathster))
charactersprites.add((mathster))

inventory = TextObject("Hit a mathster!", Font, (0,0,0), (1024,50))
charactersprites.add((inventory))
nextproblem = Input(x=825, color=(255,25,25), 

heroGroup = pygame.sprite.Group()
heroGroup.add(hero)

clock = pygame.time.Clock() 

while 1:
    events1 = pygame.event.get()

    for event in events1:
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT: sys.exit()

    if not menu:
        for events in events1:
            if event.type == MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                mouseclick = 1

        if not collisiontest and mouseclick:
            for heros in charactersprites:
                hero.movetarget()
            for mathsters in mathsterGroup:
                mathster.movetarget()
            mouseclick = 0
        screen.fill((50,100,200))
        gamebackground = GameMap()
        if not mapdrawn:
            levelmap = gamebackground.drawmap()
            mapdrawn = 1
        screen.blit(levelmap, (0,0))
        wallGroup.draw(screen)
        nextproblem.update()
        nextproblem.draw(screen)
        charactersprites.update()
        charactersprites.draw(screen)
        screen.fill((50,100,200))
        screen.blit(menubackground, (0,0))
        menusprites.update()
        menusprites.draw(screen)


    pygame.display.flip()
    clock.tick(120)
```

Thanks in advance to anyone who takes a look and is willing to lend a hand. I've been reading lots of tutorials to try to educate myself, but I've been unable to find where I've gone wrong.

Any tips to improve my code are welcome, although fixing my motionless hero is my highest priority.

EDIT to formulate a more specific question.

Comment: I solved the problem, although I'm still not sure exactly why it wasn't working. The charactersprites.update and charactersprites.draw was not updating and drawing all group members, so I split the sprites into smaller groups, and they updated and drew correctly.

Answer (score 1):

## tile id's

I suggest you use a tuple `(x,y)` for each monster/player's location. Saved as **tile-offset** rather than pixels.

When you draw, convert tile-id to pixels. It'll be ok if its offscreen.

```
def id_to_screen( tile_id width=32, height=32):
    """convert tile-coordinate to screen-coordinate (Pixels)"""
    x,y = tile_id
    x *= width
    y *= height
    return (x, y)         # unless you need: return pygame.Rect(x, y, width, height)
```

You need the reverse too, which converts mouse location to tile-ids.

```
def screen_to_id( pos, width=32, height=32):
    # converts screen pixel coordinate to world map tile offsets.
    x = pos[0] / width
    y = pos[1] / height
    return (x, y)
```

## rect

`rect.topleft` is the topleft of where the sprite is blit to. Set this to move the sprite. (Right now you are setting targetx, and reading from `self.rect`.

```
    self.rect.topleft = (384,0)

    # or
    self.rect.move_ip(384,0)
```

Remove `self.targetx` . Unless you are using it as tile-id locations on the map, instead of pixels. (If you draw a sprite, when it's Rect is offscreen, that's fine.)

Some tips:

```
    self.targetx = self.rect.topleft[0]
    self.targety = self.rect.topleft[1]

    # becomes
    self.target = self.rect.topleft
    # or
    x,y = self.rect.topleft
    # or
    self.tilex, self.tiley = self.rect.topleft
```

rect virtual attributes are useful. See : http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html#pygame.Rect . They simplify logic / remove some math.

```
    r.bottomleft = (20,30)
    r.left = 500
```

## numpy + example project

Numpy is useful for multi-dimensional arrays (roguelike 2d tile maps).
example uses a numpy array for the map. http://code.google.com/p/ninmonkey/source/browse/#hg%2Fexamples%2Fmaptiles_numpy%253Fstate%253Dclosed

Run `main.py` , press `s` to toggle scrolling tiles.

Comment: I very much appreciated the tips. They will be helpful, but I still don't understand the source of my problem. I've rephrased my question more specifically; if you can add any additional insight, I'd be most grateful.